# How to find a string in a text file, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

How do I get the number of times a certain 2 characters are used in a text files, (e.g. ('hi'))
And how do I print the sum out as an int?

I tried doing this:

```
for line in open('test.txt'):
  ly = line.split()
  for i in ly:
    a = i.count('ly')
    print(sum(a))
```

But it failed, thanks in advance!

Comment: you don't need to split the line.

Answer (score 2):

Your program fails because your variable **a** is an integer and you cannot apply the **sum** function to an integer.
Several examples have already been presented. Here is mine:

```
with open("test.txt") as fp:
    a = fp.read().count('ly')
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Different approach:

```
from collections import Counter
text = open('text.txt').read() 
word_count = Counter(text.split())
print word_count['hi']
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but if i don't split it for a line of text you will get results like: "Hi there" => Counter({'e': 2, ' ': 1, 'i': 1, 'H': 1, 'r': 1, 't': 1, 'h': 1})

Answer (score 1):

you can simply count 'ly' on each line :

```
sum(line.count('ly') for line in open('test.txt'))
```

Comment: This is great! How do I count the total number of words in the file?

Comment: You can use: print len(text.split()), but it's not always i good thing to define word count with split() for that purpose re is the best.

Comment: use line.split instead of line.count('ly') if you want the number of words.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in open('test.txt'):
    ly = line.split()
    alist = [i.count('hi') for i in ly]
print sum(alist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
for line in open('test.txt'):
    ly = line.split()
        for i in ly:
        if 'word' in i:
            a = a + 1
            print (a)
```